# How to click element that has random number in xpath or css path?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, xpath, element, watir-webdriver

I need to select month in monthpicker. 
xpath has random number

```
//*[@id="monthpicker_037945738616321245"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]
```

css path has random number too

```
#monthpicker_037945738616321245 > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(3)
```

Also 3 moth pickers on the page, but only one is visible.
Each div, that contains this monthpicker has id with random number in it.
`monthpicker_04289214732160275` or `monthpicker_04395144395656033`

```
<table class="mtz-monthpicker">
   <tbody class="mtz-monthpicker">
      <tr class="mtz-monthpicker">
         <td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" data-month="1">Январь</td>
         <td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" data-month="2">Февраль</td>
         <td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" data-month="3">Март</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="mtz-monthpicker">
         <td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" data-month="4">Апрель</td>
         <td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" data-month="5">Май</td>
         <td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" data-month="6">Июнь</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="mtz-monthpicker">
         <td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" data-month="7">Июль</td>
         <td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" data-month="8">Август</td>
         <td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" data-month="9">Сентябрь</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="mtz-monthpicker">
         <td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" data-month="10">Октябрь</td>
         <td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" data-month="11">Ноябрь</td>
         <td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" data-month="12">Декабрь</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried

```
@b.table(:class => 'mtz-monthpicker').tr(:class => 'mtz-monthpicker').td(:class => 'ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month').click
```

css path : `#monthpicker_020622412423150185 > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(3)`

xpath : `//*[@id="monthpicker_020622412423150185"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]`

Also angular.is used for this front-end.

How can I select and click a month in this monthpicker?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is by matching only part of the id value, so you don't need to hard code the random number. This can be done using XPath function `contains()` or `starts-with()` :

```
//*[contains(@id, "monthpicker_")]/.....
//*[starts-with(@id, "monthpicker_")]/.....
```

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation I will go for text based `xpath` search. That's my favorite.

```
//*[.='Март'] //if the text is unique
```

With `.` we can filter down to parent node directly and look for matching text. However, you mentioned the UI is build on `Angular`. I am not sure how `Watir` handles angular that does not work pretty good with `webdriver` so you may need to add some additional wait before that.

Comment: I use watir-webdrievr. I tried:  @b.td(:xpath, "//*[contains(@id, 'monthpicker_')]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]").when_present.click
  @b.td(:xpath, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'monthpicker_')]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]").when_present.click
  @b.td(:xpath, "//*[.='Март']").when_present.click But I got only timed out after 90 seconds, waiting for {:xpath=> ....

Comment: And what happened after that?

Comment: this xpath works, but this element is not currently visible and selenium can't interact with it. Also this element does not have any styles that would make it hidden. But it has parent with overflow:hidden style. I tried to change visibility of the parent element with javascript with the code: monthPikerOverflow = @b.div(:xpath, "//*[contains(@id, 'monthpicker_')]")
  script = <<-JS
    arguments[0].style.overflow = 'visible';
    arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
  JS
  @b.execute_script(script, monthPikerOverflow) , but it did not help. So i keep looking for solution.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Or use [imgur](http://imgur.com/) to upload a screenshot and demonstrate what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you need to also check for visibility, I do not think you can use just XPath or CSS.

To find the monthpicker that is visible, get all of the divs that have "monthpicker" in the id. Personally, I find using a regexp easier than an xpath/css:

```
monthpicker = @b.divs(id: /monthpicker_/).find(&present?)
```

Then you can interact with the monthpicker to click one of the cells. For example, clicking the first cell:

```
monthpicker.td.when_present.click
```

Or clicking a specific index (the third one in this case):

```
monthpicker.td(index: 2).when_present.click
```

Though I think it might be more clear to select the td based on its data-month attribute:

```
monthpicker.td(data_month: "3").when_present.click
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your suggestions.

```
monthpicker = @b.tds(:xpath, "//*[contains(@id, 'monthpicker_')]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]")
puts monthpicker.size
```

resulted in 4 elements

This worked for me

```
monthpicker.each do |x|
script = <<-JS
arguments[0].click();
JS
@b.execute_script(script, x)
end
```

if I use x.click then I would get "Element is not currently visible" because I guess some parent elements have overflow:hidden property. But JS works.